# How to transform cutom class ServiceUnavailabeErrorValve declared in server.xml that still uses javax in order to upgrade to Java 21?

Tags: java, docker, server.xml

There is a custom class ServiceUnavailabeErrorValve declared in server.xml that uses javax.
Docker fails to run as it copy server.xml and project's war separatly.
I solved the project's issues as it uses external services with javax by applying transformer eclipse plugin. However  still don't know how to aply transformer to server.xml file.

Thanks!

I havent any clue how to solve it.

Comment: Hi, can you post the snippet of server.xml file that references the ServiceUnavailabeErrorValve class? Do you know where the class is defined? Is it in standard Tomcat installation, or is it some JAR file you add to Tomcat? If it's the latter, you should transform that JAR file too.